# Terraform fails without any error message

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I am trying to execute Terraform commands from GitLab but I am unable to execute this successfully.

Following are the contents of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
plan:k8stest:
  image: 
    name: hashicorp/terraform:latest
  stage: plan
  environment:
    name: k8s-test
  before_script:
    - terraform version
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform fmt -check -recursive
    - terraform init
    - terraform validate
    - terraform plan
```

It executes `'terraform fmt'` command but after that it bails out without any error message

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ terraform version
Terraform v1.0.2
on linux_amd64
$ cd ${TF_ROOT}
$ terraform fmt -check -recursive
backend.tf
service.tf
terraform.tfvars
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /builds/SathishKumar/ultestdevops/terraform/plan.json: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload
```

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong and why `terraform init` was not executed.

Answer (score 6):

Your `terraform fmt -check -recursive` command is showing that it wants to format `backend.tf`, `service.tf` and `terraform.tfvars`.

When running in [`-check` mode, `terraform fmt` will exit with a non zero exit status](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/fmt.html#check) when it detects that files needed to be formatted.